# MySQL Select based on count of substring in a column?

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have two tables (I'm trying to remove everything irrelevant to the question from the tables and make some sample ones, so bear with me :)

```
    ___________________         ________________________
    |File             |         |Content               |
    |_________________|         |______________________|
    |ID Primary Key   | 1     * |ID Primary Key        |
    |URL Varcher(255) |---------|FileID Foreign Key    |
    |_________________|         |    ref File(ID)      |
                                |FileContent Text      |
                                |______________________|
```

A File has a url.  There may be many Content items corresponding to each File.

I need to create a query using these tables that I'm having some trouble with.  I essentially want the query, in simple terms, to say:

"Select the file URL and the **sum of the times substring "X" appears in all content entries associated with that file**."

I'm pretty good with SQL selects, but I'm not so good with aggregate functions and it's letting me down.  Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query won't be efficient but might give you a hint:

```
SELECT url, cnt
FROM (
  SELECT
    f.id,
    IFNULL(
      SUM(
        (LENGTH(c.text) - LENGTH(REPLACE(c.text, f.url, '')))/LENGTH(f.url)
      ),
      0
    ) as cnt
  FROM file c
  JOIN content c ON f.id = c.fileid
  GROUP BY f.id
) cnts JOIN file USING(id);
```

To append files that do not have a match in the content table you can `UNION ALL` the rest of use `LEFT JOIN` in the `cnts` subquery.

Comment: Thanks for the solution - sorry for not marking an answer yet but I won't have time to try this till the weekend, busy work week :)

Answer (score 1):

This solution attempts to use `REGEXP` to match the substring.  `REGEXP` returns 1 if it matches, 0 if not, so `SUM()` them up for the total.  `REGEXP` might seem like overkill, but would allow for more complicated matching than a simple substring.

```
SELECT
  File.ID,
  File.URL,
  SUM(Content.FileContent REGEXP 'substring') AS numSubStrs
FROM File LEFT JOIN Content ON File.ID = Content.ID
GROUP BY File.ID, File.URL;
```

The easier method if a more complex match pattern won't ever be needed uses `LIKE` and `COUNT(*)` instead of `SUM()`:

```
SELECT
  File.ID,
  File.URL,
  COUNT(*) AS numSubStrs
FROM File LEFT JOIN Content ON File.ID = Content.ID
WHERE Content.FileContent LIKE '%substring%'
GROUP BY File.ID, File.URL;
```

Note the use of `LEFT JOIN`, which should produce 0 when there are not actually any entries in `Content`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution - sorry for not marking an answer yet but I won't have time to try this till the weekend, busy work week :)